# Iterate through every .jpg or .jpeg file in directory and sub directory

Tags: ruby

I want to iterate through every jpg/jpeg file in a directory and every subdirectory and every subdirectory of that sub-directory and so on. I want to be able to go through every single image file in a folder. Is there an easy way to do this or would a recursive method work best?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dir.glob("your_directory/**/*.{jpg,jpeg}")
```

Comment: Does this iterate through every subdirectory past 2 subdirectories down? And also get files in the home directory?

Comment: It goes past two subdirectories. It will not go into the home directory unless the home directory is under whatever you put as 
`your_directory`.

Comment: I think my wording is off. Will this go through every file in the directory no matter how many folders deep it is?